# jQuery rotate (revolve by degrees) background image

Tags: jquery, rotation, jquery-animate, background-image

## What I need:

An animated rotation (revolution) of a background image by an arbitrary amount of degrees. Ideally the animation is activated on the call-back of another animation.

## What I have:

A container div with a background image that contains additional divs (only the image is required to rotate and not the div or div content).

## Terminological confusion:

In jQuery, the word "rotate" seems to mean **cyclically interchange**. My definition of "rotate", for the purposes of this thread, refers to **the two dimensional revolution by degrees of an object using the z-plane as a central axis**. The terminological overlap makes it difficult to research this matter using search engines.

## Disappointment:

I expected something as basic as the animated rotation (revolution) of an image or background image to be a standard requirement and therefore a default functionality of jQuery. Instead, the best I can find is a jquery-rotate plugin that doesn't highlight obvious support for background-images and what it does support, isn't even cross-browser friendly.

**EDIT:** *The jquery-rotate plugin supports IE6+ and other older browsers by falling back to CANVAS and VML for standard objects though I'm as of yet uncertain as to what the support is for background-images.*

## Cross-browser:

Cross-browser support is essential. For this reason, CSS alternatives or jQuery/CSS hybrid alternatives will not meet my requirements. A minimum of IE6+ support is acceptable.

## My question:

Am I overlooking obvious solutions or is jQuery not able to animate the rotation (revolution) of a background image despite being able to achieve far more complex feats?

Comment: I'm open to relatively positioning an image element as opposed to augmenting a background-image if needs be.

Answer (score 0):

Kinetic.js with HTML canvas offers some easy and effective rotate functions you might try where you can set a degree of rotation that you want --- I used it to animate the ball on www.threeblokesfromchina.com , you can also google for tutorials

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation IanO.S. but from what I understand, the IE9+ support of HTML canvas is way beyond the minimum cross-browser support I require (IE6+). Furthermore, HTML canvas seems to be exclusively for drawing rather than my requirement, rotating image elements (or more precisely, background-images).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there's no real way of animating a `background-image` — however you achieve this, you'll need to create a separate element (more on this in footnote #1).

Secondly, rotation is not a straightforward concept, but in the cutting-edge standards-compliant world it's possible using a combination of CSS3 `transform`s and `transition`s.

Thirdly, IE6 will need to use proprietary non-standard tech to emulate this. VML is one option but Microsoft actually implemented a lot of CSS3 using the proprietary [filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847(v=vs.85).aspx) property. Transitions are not possible, but you can use Javascript to dynamically modify the `filter` and `transform` properties over time.

Still, all this requires a lot of polyfilling and a custom out of the box solution developed elsewhere is your best bet. My recommendation would be to use the excellent [CSS Sandpaper](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/04/05/cross-browser-animated-css-transforms-even-in-ie/).

#### 1. Creating a separate DOM element to contain the image

Something like this should work (I've used `<b></b>` for its lack of semantic implication):

```
<div class="container">
    <b class="background"></b>
    <div class="foreground">
        [content/]
    <div>
</div>

.container, 
.foreground {
    position: relative;
}

.background {
    background: yourImage.jpg;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```